# Parse JSON and delegate to defaultDeserializer within a JsonDeserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

In order to deserialize a map i need to read a property within my json object.

I added a custom deserializer that parses the json and sets the found type within a context attribute. This attribute is later used within a second deserializer that deserializes a custom map of the user.

Unfortunately this solution fails since i'm changing the currentToken of the jsonParser. The defaultDeserializer is therefore not able to continue parsing the response.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:144)
>     at
>   UserDeserializer.deserialize(UserDeserializer.java:36)

```
@Override
public User deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
    JsonNode typeNode = node.get("type");
    String typeName = schemaNode.get("name").textValue();
    ctxt.setAttribute("typeName", typeName);

    User userResponse = (User) defaultDeserializer.deserialize(jsonParser, ctxt);
    return userResponse;

}
```

My json looks like this:

```
{
  "username": "test",
  "type": { "name": "testtype" },
  "map": { "test": 1234 }
}
```

Is there a way to reset the json parser or use a different one? Or could a specific JsonNode be used for deserializing?

Changing the json is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now using different approach. It is possible to get the current JsonNode like this:

```
    JsonNode rootNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
```

The underlying json can be fetched using:

```
    rootNode.toString().
```

I store the refernce to another nodemapper during the construction of the JsonDeserializer. I then use this mapper to deserialize the remaining json:

```
    mapper.readValue(rootNode.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the objectMapper instead

```
@Override
public User deserialize(String jsonString) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    User user = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, User.class);

    return user;

}
```

Or use the ObjectMapper and populate the User from it setters if it has any.

```
@Override
public User deserialize(String jsonString) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    map = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, HashMap.class);
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(map.get("username"));
    user.setType(map.get("type"));
    user.setMap(map.get("map"));

    return user;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is solving the problem. It just shows how to deserialize json in two different ways. Can you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: I'm sorry.  Maybe I didn't understand the original question at hand.  The stack trace and code snippet isn't clear and I thought you were trying to desalinize the Json object into  an object.